# Implementation of Enhanced Ecommerce in Google Analytics

Tags: magento, google-analytics, e-commerce

I am confused while trying to implement enhanced Google analytic code for my Magento website. I have few things in my mind which is not resolved till yet after reading lots of Internet pages:

1. On which page should i put the code? in all pages or only thank you
   page.
2. What code should be implemented to track revenues from various
   sources live classic analytic.
3. What are the code which can take the values form Magento?

Answer (score 0):

The enhanced E-commerce plugin allows tracking of many things. The main tracking is off course your order which is only on the thank you page. But that is basic E-commerce tracking.

The enhanced means tracking every step of the way, meaning tracking from [product imporessions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-impression) (viewing the product page), [adding/remove from basket](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#add-remove-cart) and all steps of the checkout.

Basically before the Enhanced Ecommerce module you had to implement Events into your code which did these things, but now with the ecommerce plugin you can track a lot more data about products and coupons and your checkout.

So in short:

1) On almost all pages of your website

2) Revenue is simply the order completion/thank you page code[(transactions)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-transactions)

3) This I can not answer since I have never worked with Magento before.